# Minimum swap operations

Tags: algorithm

The array **a[]** consist of only **1's and 0's**.

We want to get a continuous sequence of 1's **(greater or equal to n)** by swapping positions.

How to perform such task in minimum swap operations.

**We can swap any two positions.**

**Here output minimum number swap operations required to create a consecutive segment of greater or equal to n 1's from array a[]**.

**Length of array<=10^5.**

For example-

```
INPUT:

a[5]={1,0,1,0,1}

n=2

OUTPUT:

1
```

Comment: So the output should be the number of swaps? Or the instructions for carrying the swaps out?

Comment: Instead of swapping you can add/subtract. Like loop through you array -> whenever you find `1` do a subtract `1-1` and for `0` do addition like `0+1`. Since the array contains only 0's and 1's.

Comment: Output should be minimum number of swap operations needed.

Comment: @user2826957 Only adjacent swaps?

Comment: @jonrsharpe -We can swap any two positions.

Comment: @user2826957 then please update the question to provide the appropriate information

Comment: Can you create another temporary array ? If you can, then it's easy. For each element in your initial array, if it's a `1`, add a `1` to your temporary array. When you're done, fill the new array with zeros, and it's done !

Comment: Please remember to show your own attempt at solving the problem in the question.

Comment: @Theox Can you explain a little more

Comment: Once you've solved this you might care to take a look at the "Dutch national flag problem" which involves sorting 0s, 1s and 2s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the array from the left, keeping track of the count of 1's in the `n` positions to the left of the current position.

This can easily be done by, for each element, increasing a counter if it's a 1 and decreasing the counter if the element `n` positions to the left is a 1.

Now all we need to do is keep track of the maximum above count - `n - this` will be the minimum number of swaps.

Oh, and we should probably go through and check that there is actually `n` 1's in the array.

This will take `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Scan from the front until you get a 0, then scan from the back until you get a 1. Swap them. The swap was necessary, and it should be clear that these two elements won't need to be swapped again. Repeat the process from the current positions until your reference indices meet in the middle.

All necessary swaps will be done, and each element that needs to be swapped will only have it happen once.  I can't see how you could do fewer swaps than that.

Comment: The final position may not be optimal. It could be better to move all the 1s to the right rather than the left.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to sort your array `a[4]={1,0,1,0}` to `a[4]={1,1,0,0}` with minimum number of swaps.

Probably it may not need any swapping like below

```
int a[4]={1,0,1,0}

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
if(a[i] == 1 && a[i+1] != a[i+2])
{
a[i+1] = a[i+1]+a[i+2];
a[i+2] = a[i+1]-a[i+2];
a[i+1] = a[i+1]-a[i+2];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an array of 1s and 0s. We want to find the number of swaps required to end up with a continuous sequence of n 1s:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
```

There are 4 possible final arrangements for this array. The number of swaps required
for each arrangement is the number of 0s in the original array that are
in the same position as a 1 in the final array:

```
1, 1, 1, ?, ?, ? - 1 swap
?, 1, 1, 1, ?, ? - 2 swaps
?, ?, 1, 1, 1, ? - 1 swap
?, ?, ?, 1, 1, 1 - 1 swap
```

This can be found in linear time by creating two arrays: a running total
of the number of 0s to the left of any index, and the number of 0s to the
right of any index. Iterate through all the possible final arrangements, and
calculate the number of swaps by adding the appropriate values from these two
arrays.

Comment: Here We don't have to get a continuous sequence of all 1's but only n number of continuous 1's.

Comment: @user2826957 OK, the idea should still work. Make the number of 1s in the final array equal to n, and lookup the number of 0s within the block of 1s in the original array.